# Fade in overlay in modal dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I have a JQuery UI dialog which is modal and has a black background with 50% opacity.  Is it possible to make the background opacity fade from 0% to 50%?  If so, how?  Because currently it feels kind of like getting a punch straight to the face when a dialog is shown.

FWIW, this is the CSS I'm using at the moment:

```
.ui-widget-overlay {
    background: black;
    opacity: 0.5;
    filter: alpha(opacity = 50);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the jQuery `fadeTo()` function. More information can be found on the link below.
http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/fadeTo#speedopacitycallback

Comment: Perfect, I can't believe I didn't think of that!

Answer (score 38):

You could also add this to fadeIn the modal:

```
$(loginForm).dialog({
        resizable: false,
        open: function(){
            $('.ui-widget-overlay').hide().fadeIn();
        },
        show: "fade",
        hide: "fade" 
});
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: That works great for me. I'd also like it to fade out when the dialog is closed, but for some reason reversing the code you have in the open function doesn't do it... "close: function(){$'.ui-widget-overlay').fadeOut();}"

Answer (score 8):

This is an expansion on Liam Potter's answer. His works great for the fade in, but doesn't handle the fade out. I found this the easiest way to make the background also fade back out:

```
beforeClose: function(){
    $('.ui-widget-overlay:first')
        .clone()
        .appendTo('body')
        .show()
        .fadeOut(400, function(){ 
            $(this).remove(); 
        })
    ;
}
```

You can't do this in the "close" method because jQuery has already removed the '.ui-widget-overlay' container, however by cloning it to just do the fade you can sidestep their removal and still make use of all the default styles.

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an old question, but I came across it just now in a search, and feel I could help other people.

This could be improved I'm sure but this will fade in and out your overlay when using a jQuery UI dialog.

```
open: function(){
    $('.ui-widget-overlay').hide().fadeIn();
},
beforeClose: function(){
    $('.ui-widget-overlay').remove();
    $("<div />", {
        'class':'ui-widget-overlay'
    }).css(
        {
            height: $("body").outerHeight(),
            width: $("body").outerWidth(),
            zIndex: 1001
        }
    ).appendTo("body").fadeOut(function(){
        $(this).remove();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a minor improvement on Liam Potter's answer. If you want the overlay to be full-screen then you might change his code to use the `$(document).height()` and `$(document).width()` instead of the body, because the latter be measured smaller than the visible area.

```js
open: function(){
    $('.ui-widget-overlay').hide().fadeIn();
},
beforeClose: function(){
    $('.ui-widget-overlay').remove();
    $("<div />", {
        'class':'ui-widget-overlay'
    }).css({
        height: $(document).height(),
        width: $(document).width(),
        zIndex: 1001
    }).appendTo("body").fadeOut(function(){
        $(this).remove();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create your own widget extending $.ui.dialog to add overlay show and hide animations with accurate configuration using option.

Another lacking functionality to close dialog by click on overlay is also easily added:

in some file, say jquery-ui.fsrc.dialog.js:

```
(function( $, undefined ) {

$.widget('fsrc.fsrc_dialog', $.ui.dialog, {
open: function() {
    // some helpful vars
    var self = this,
        options = self.options;

    // call parent method - it will create overlay and save it in self.overlay variable
    var ret = $.ui.dialog.prototype.open.apply(this, arguments);

    if (options.showOverlay) {
        // immediately hide and animate overlay
        // kind a hack, but jquery ui developers left no better way
        self.overlay.$el.hide().show(options.showOverlay)
    }
    if (options.closeOnOverlay) {
        // close dialog on click on overlay
        self.overlay.$el.click(function() {
            self.close();
        })
    }
    return ret;
},
close: function(event) {
    var self = this,
        options = self.options;

    if (options.hideOverlay) {
        // save and unset self.overlay, so it will not be destroyed by parent function during animation
        var overlay = self.overlay
        self.overlay = null;
        overlay.$el.hide(options.hideOverlay, function() {
            // destroy overlay after animation as parent would do
            overlay.destroy();
        })
    }

    // call parent method
    var ret = $.ui.dialog.prototype.close.apply(this, arguments);
    return ret;
}
});

}(jQuery));
```

In page:

```
<script src='/js/jquery-ui.fsrc.dialog.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('#show').click(function(){
            jQuery('#order_form_container').fsrc_dialog({
                modal: true,
                closeOnOverlay: true,
                show: {effect: "fade", duration: 500},
                showOverlay: {effect: "fade", duration: 500},
                hide: {effect: "fade", duration: 300},
                hideOverlay: {effect: "fade", duration: 300},
            });
        })
    })
-->
</script>`
```

I named namespace, widget and options to my favor.

Tested jquery1.7.2, jquery-ui1.8.19, IE9, ff11, chrome18.0.1025.168m, opera11.61

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.ui-widget-overlay').hide().fadeIn();
```

This effect has issue on IE as the opacity won't work after fade in

Comment: Why give an answer that's not helping and has issues in a browser?

Answer (score 0):

I had to modify the answer from Sam Barnes to make it work (I also threw the dialog click function in a $(document).ready function):

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  $(".dialog").click(function(){
    $('.ui-widget-overlay').hide().fadeIn();        
    $("div.dialog").dialog({
        resizable: false,
        close: function(){
            $('.ui-widget-overlay').hide();
        },
        show: "fade",
        hide: "fade" 
    });
    $(".ui-dialog").fadeIn();
    return false;
  });
  $(".ui-widget-overlay").click(function(){
    $(this).hide();
    $(".ui-dialog").hide();
  });
</script>
<style>
  .ui-widget-overlay {
    background: black;
    opacity: 0.5;
    filter: alpha(opacity = 50);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
   }
</style>
<div class='ui-widget-overlay'></div>
<div class='dialog' title='Heading!'>Some Message!</div>
```

You can add the thing that hides on escape button press by adding:

```
$(document).keyup(function(e) {

  if (e.keyCode == 27) { 
       $(".ui-dialog").hide();
       $('.ui-widget-overlay').hide();
  }
});
```