# How to get background to fade when jQuery Dialog box is active

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a jQuery dialog box which appears when a button is pressed. I want the background to fade out colour (dim) when the dialog box is open.

What do I have to put or replace in the CSS to achieve this.

Here is the code:

```
// Button that brings up a dialog box
<div id="dialog" title="Sign in" style="display:none">
    Sign in
</div>

 // jQuery dialog function
<script>
    function check_domain_input()
    {        
        $( "#dialog" ).dialog(); 

        var domain_val = document.getElementsByName('domain');

        if (domain_val[0].value.length > 0)
        {
            return true;
        }

        $( "#dialog" ).dialog();


        return false;


    }
</script>
```

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3945123/how-to-make-jquery-dialog-modal.

Comment: You must be have vision impairments, because it's no way a duplicate

Comment: Maybe this one will be of some help then: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/751796/fade-in-overlay-in-modal-dialog

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A modal dialog prevents the user from interacting with the rest of the page until it is closed.

```
$("#dialog").dialog({modal: true});
```

Comment: Can I change the fade opacity and colour of the fade? Is there a way?